# jQuery alter button value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reset the text of a button tag. When the user clicks on the button a ajax call is made and then changes the title of the button to the response message ( success or fail) And I need it to change back to Save if they want to make more changes. right now it just stays on the response message

```
// SAVE NEW STUDENT DETAILS
  $('#save_student_detail_changes').live('click',function(){
    $('#save_student_detail_changes').text('Save');
    var changes ='&';
    // FIND ALL THE INPUT CHILDREN OF #STUDENT_DETAILS AND INSERT THE VALUE ATTRIBUTE AND THE COL ATTRIBUTE INTO THEIR OWN VARIABLES
     $('#student_details').find("input").each(function() { 
      var value = $(this).attr('value');// VARIABLE FOR VALUE ATTRIBUTE OF INPUT TAG
      var column = $(this).attr('col');// VARIABLE FOR COL ATTRIBUTE OF INPUT TAG
      changes += column + '=' + value + '&' ;// BUILDS THE AJAX QUERY STRING
      var lin = $(this).parent().attr('rel');// GET ID ATTRIBUTE DETAILS
      $(this).parent().attr('id',lin);// MAKE NEW ATTRIBUTE WITH DETAILS FROM ID ATTRIBUTE
      $(this).parent().removeAttr('rel');// REMOVE ID ATTRIBUTE
      $(this).replaceWith(value); // REPLACE INPUT ELEMENT WITH VALUE THAT WAS INSERTED

      });
      $(this) // AJAX CALL
        .html(ajax_load) // SHOW LOADING SPINNING WHEEL
        .load(loadUrl,"form_being_submitted=save_student_detail_changes"+changes);
      $(this).fadeOut(3000);// FADE OUT SAVE BUTTON
```

Comment: What does the user do that indicates they want to make more changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the .ajax() method. There is has a lot more control.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/